# Angular 2 - Joins

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two objects - hours and customers.

```
this.customer = Customers[]
this.hour = Hours[]
```

In both objects i have the customer_id field - now i want to create a new list containing the detail from the hour list combined with the customer_name from the customer list.

```
this.hourswithcustomers[] = ?
```

How can i join these two objects/lists to a new list to get the following result?

```
| hour.hour_id | hour.hour_amount | hour.customer_id | customer.customer_name |
| 1            | 500.00           | 99               | microsoft              |
| 2            | 300.00           | 55               | apple                  |
| 3            | 200.00           | 99               | microsoft              |
```

Comment: Is this an issue with constructing the hour-table.component.html view?

Comment: I would like to create a list containing the info of Hours[[ combined with the customers name from Customers[] Both objects have the field customer_id which can be used for the join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to merge the two would be a combination of a map of customerId `->` Customer. Then from there you can loop over the hours to populate the `hourswithcustomers` object.

Mapping the Data:

```
var customerMap = {};
this.customer.forEach((customer) => {
    customerMap[customer.customer_id] = customer;
})

this.hourswithcustomers = this.hour.map((hour) => {
     return {
         hour: hour,
         customer: customerMap[hour.customer_id]
     };
});
```

On your view you can display it like so:

```
<tr *ngFor="let hwc of hourswithcustomers">
    <td>{{hwc.hour.hour_id}}</td>
    <td>{{hwc.hour.hour_amount }}</td>
    <td>{{hwc.hour.customer_id}}</td>
    <td>{{hwc.customer.customer_name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this will work but maybe try this:

```
 <tr *ngFor="let h of hourswithcustomer">
    <td > {{h.hour.hour_id}}</td>
    <td > {{h.hour.hour_amount }}</td>
    <td > {{h.customer.customer_id}}</td>
    <td > {{h.customer.customer_customername}}</td>
</tr>


this.hourswithcustomers = this.hours.map( hour => { 
    return {hour, customer: this.find(c.customerId)}
});
```

where `find()` is a method to find the customer with the id. I don't know your code I can't invent how you find it.

Comment: how would i create the list hourswithcustomer?

Comment: @phicon sry for the multiple edits, I hope you get the gist of it lol. just concatenate the two array into one array of object containing the two..